# Is it possible to send a custom HTTP request

Tags: javascript

With javascript you can do it with xmlhttp.open, what other ways can do this?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521149/http-request-from-javascript-using-raw-message-including-headers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463624/how-can-i-send-raw-data-in-an-http-get-request

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want a POST method, with jQuery :

```
$.get('test.html',{foo: 'bar'}, function(data) {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: maybe insert the data object, to serve the needs: `$.get('test.html',{foo: 'bar'}, function(data) {`

Comment: but won't that use get paramaters in the URL request rather than send the data in the body like POST would?

Comment: Thierry, as I understand, this sends the data in format urlpage.php?data. not urlpage.php alone (like a POST request would which uses the body)..